# WScript.Shell Run gives "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation." when opening images.

Tags: silverlight-5.0, wsh

I am facing an issue while trying to open an image file from a Silverlight app in Windows 10 using WScript.Shell.

The code is as follows.

```
        try
        {
            dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
            shell.Run(@"C:\temp\X.jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

This piece of code works perfectly fine when the default application is set to 'Photos' / 'Internet Explorer' in Windows 10 'Default Apps' settings.

However, when the default app is set to 'Paint', I get an exception
"No application is associated with the specified file for this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070483)"

Please note that when I try to double click on the same image in Windows explorer, it opens up in Paint application without errors.

Why does this happen? 
Please help.

Comment: Can this be a x64 vs x86 issue ? Your shell is started using either of those. When referencing IE, it picks the matching version (by luck?) and when referencing Paint, it is the non-matching thus it does not see it.

Comment: try @"start C:\temp\X.jpg" - sorry can't test right now

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

- windows script host not running desired application for known file type

### Solution

- expressly specify the desired application and run using `WScript.Shell` Object

### Example

- in the example below, we reference both the program and the file we want to run with `strRunLine`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <package>
  <job id="default">
      <script language="jscript">
      <![CDATA[
          // save to demo_runpaint.wsf
          var WshShell        =   new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
          var strRunLine      =   "";

          strRunLine  = "mspaint.exe C:/path/to/capture.png";
          WshShell.Run( strRunLine );
      ]]>
      </script>
  </job>
  </package>
  ```

### Pitfalls

- the desired program must be in your system PATH or else you must specify the full path to the application expressly.